# Why does char hello[14] = "Hello, World!\n"; result in a string size of 40

Tags: c, string

I have the following C code:

```
char hello[14] = "Hello, World!\n\0";
printf("strlen(\"Hello, World!\") = %d\n", strlen(&hello[0]));
```

This results in:

```
strlen("Hello, World!") = 40
```

However if I change my code to:

```
char hello[] = "Hello, World!\n\0";
printf("strlen(\"Hello, World!\") = %d\n", strlen(&hello[0]));
```

I get the correct value of 14.

When I don't explicitly tell the compiler how many bytes the string takes up it gives me an incorrect strlen value and seems to not null terminate the string.

I have found answers of people having similar problems but not a good explanation of why.

If anyone could explain this to me it'd be appreciated.

Comment: `"Hello, World!\n\0"` is 16 `char`s.

Comment: incorrect format specifier in printf too, use `%zu` to print the result of `strlen`, or cast result to `(int)`

Comment: Actually 16 characters. The string literal gets another zero terminator at the end.

Comment: You say that 14 is the correct value but in the next paragraph say that it gives you an incorrect value ...

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the version giving `40` was actually `char hello[14] = "Hello, World!\n";`

Comment: Also, I would use strlen(hello) instead of strlen(&hello[0]).

Comment: As M.M says: if the string exactly fits the specified size then the `'\0'` terminator is omitted. Therefore `strlen` has chanced upon another terminator that happened to be there.

Comment: @M.M Same result with or without the null terminator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is a constraint violation:

```
char hello[14] = "Hello, World!\n\0";
```

There are 15 characters inside the quote marks but the array is only size 14. It is excess initializers for aggregate.

So the results of any executable are completely undefined. The compiler should give a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 3):

```
  char hello[14] = "Hello, World!\n\0";
```

should be

```
char hello[] = "Hello, World!\n";
```

Your string can't fit into 14 characters.

Array out of bound access can lead to undefined behavior.

No need of explicitly adding a nul character at the end of the string as character array will do it implicitly but you should have space for it.

Comment: I get the same behaviour without including the \0.

Comment: @JoeCarter note that the array bound is also omitted in the version without `\0`

Comment: Note the point is not `\0` it is about the size of your array.. When you can't fit your string into the size of the array and start accessing it then you have undefned behavior.